# Javascript: pass variable to arrow function instead of setting harcoded value

Tags: javascript

How to replace value `1` by the variable `x` when setting an `onclick` function to a `td` like below:

```
var sounds = [1, 3, 8, 12];
var x = 123;
mytd.onclick = () => play(sounds[1].toString());
```

Comment: `() => play(sound[1].toString());` -> `() => play(sound[x].toString());`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want "currying"?

```js
var sounds = [1, 3, 8, 12];
const playSound = (snd) => () => play(sounds[snd].toString());

var x = 123;
mytd.onclick = playSound(x)
```